# getting wrong user with laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel-sanctum

I am using Laravel Sanctum to provide a personal access token to my clients.
I am using these guards in auth.php:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'hash' => false
        ]
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
        ],
    ],
```

I give my clients tokens using the following code:

```
    $client = Client::find($id);
    $token = $client->createToken('CLIENT_TOKEN');
```

but whenever I try to access the user with `$request->user()` I get the wrong user. while the token is completely different from what the retrieved user is.
I am using laravel-swoole package as my webserver.

Comment: I have the same problem but only on Swoole configuration. I think it has something to do with it. Did you come up with the solution? (And do you even remember it?)